# MongoDB query for date based document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection wit documents that have a Date field, I need to find the document with the latest date that is also before a specific date I provide.
Say I have documents with the following dates

2000,
2003,
2004,
2006,
2010,
2011

I need to find a document that is the max date but prior to a date I provide, for example 
db.collection.find(2005) -> will return 2004
db.collection.find(2000) -> will return null
db.collection.find(2015) -> will return 2011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming dates are stored with field name: "date",
we can get the required result using the below query -

```
db.collection.find({date:{$lt:2004}}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1)
```

returns :

[image]